# PHP directory listening with permissions

Tags: php, file, permissions, directory, apache2

I have a webpage (apache2) which is based on Linux ubuntu server 14.04 LTS (32bit).

I successfully found, according to me, a good and simple PHP directory/file listener.

My problem is: I don't know how to show the directories/files which have *0700* permission. I also would like to open the file. I don't want to change the permissions because on my webpage, the users have to login to use the website. I mean the files which have *0700* permission are not public, and I want that just the members of the website can use/download the files.

My [code](http://pastebin.com/WTMeUGP0) is:

```
<?php
    $dirlist = getFileList("./uf/");
?>
<table border="1">
<thead>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Type</th><th>Size</th><th>Last Modified</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?PHP
        // output file list as table rows
        foreach($dirlist as $file) {
        echo "<tr>\n";
        echo "<td><a href=\"{$file['name']}\">",basename($file['name']),"</a></td>\n";
        echo "<td>{$file['type']}</td>\n";
        echo "<td>{$file['size']}</td>\n";
        echo "<td>",date('r', $file['lastmod']),"</td>\n";
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php
    function getFileList($dir, $recurse=false)
    {
        $retval = array();

        // add trailing slash if missing
        if(substr($dir, -1) != "/") $dir .= "/";

        // open pointer to directory and read list of files
        $d = @dir($dir) or die("getFileList: Failed opening directory $dir for reading");
        while(false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
            // skip hidden files
            if($entry[0] == ".") continue;
            if(is_dir("$dir$entry")) {
                $retval[] = array(
                "name" => "$dir$entry/",
                "type" => filetype("$dir$entry"),
                "size" => 0,
                "lastmod" => filemtime("$dir$entry")
                );
                if($recurse && is_readable("$dir$entry/")) {
                    $retval = array_merge($retval, getFileList("$dir$entry/", true));
                }
            } elseif(is_readable("$dir$entry")) {
                $retval[] = array(
                "name" => "$dir$entry",
                "type" => mime_content_type("$dir$entry"),
                "size" => filesize("$dir$entry"),
                "lastmod" => filemtime("$dir$entry")
            );
            }
        }
        $d->close();

        return $retval;
    }
?>
```

I hope you can understand what I'm talking about.

Comment: This is by design. The webserver can only access parts of the system that are publicly readable, so that bugs in scripts won't inadvertently leak private information.

Comment: You should paste the code into the question using the [edit] button.